# Can we able to change GCP cloud build settings using terraform or gcloud command

Tags: terraform, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a use-case where I need to enable cloud build access on GKE but I did not found a terraform resource to do that, also not found gcloud CLI command to do the same.
[image]

Comment: You can add the role to the service account using `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} --member=serviceAccount:${PROJECT_NUM}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/container.developer`. I'm unfamiliar with how to do this using Terraform.

Comment: The Cloud Build service account email address required the project number. You can determine this (`${PROJECT_NUM}`) manually or use `PROJECT_NUM=$(gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} --format="value(projectNumber)")`

Comment: Please have a look into the following [Terraform Official Documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_service_account_iam.html) to add permissions to the service account.

Comment: Also please have a look into the following [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/managing-infrastructure-as-code#granting_permissions_to_your_cloud_build_service_account) where it's explained what @DazWilkin commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in Terraform by creating a `google_project_iam_member` for the Cloud Build service account that's created by default when you enable the Cloud Build API. For example:

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "cloudbuild_kubernetes_policy" {
  project = var.project_id 
  role = "roles/container.developer"
  member = "serviceAccount:${var.project_number}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

The value declared in the role attribute/key corresponds to a role in the console user interface (an image of which you have included above).